# Rotation of plane around y axis

Tags: math, geometry, trigonometry

I’m building a small web-based game that uses the computer’s built-in or attached camera. I’m using Machine Learning to recognize the user’s face and then have an avatar on the screen mimic the user’s movement (i.e. when the user’s face gets closer to the camera, the avatar gets bigger since the user’s face is closer to the camera; when the user moves right, the avatar moves right too).

One of my friends has a large monitor in front of him and then the laptop sits to his right. Hence, when he moves closer to the bigger monitor, the avatar shows him moving left, since the camera is to his right. This makes sense but I was wondering, from a mathematical point of view, given a set of (x, y) coordinates for the user’s nose, eyes and ears, how could I possibly rotate this set of coordinates around the y axis. We can assume that the camera sits 45 degrees to the right of my friend.

I’m hoping that with this rotation, when he moves closer to the screen he’s facing, the avatar will become bigger, mimicking his exact movements, despite the fact that the camera is to his right. One particular problem I’m struggling with is the size of the avatar - when the camera is to the right and the user moves left, the avatar becomes smaller since the face is moving away from the camera, but this shouldn’t be the case.

I’ve added the option to ask the user where the camera is positioned, but I need help with finding a plane rotation that will solve the issue above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the math section of the Three.js library, especially the Plane and Matrix4 items. Your can check the code of how a matrix4 is applied to a Plane: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Plane.js#L200

Comment: Are you talking about a 2D or a 3D rotation? You write about (x, y) coordinates, suggesting 2D, but also about rotating around an axis, which suggests 3D.